# Agregar elemento nuevo a diccionario Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Quiero agregar en un ciclo **for** nuevos elementos a un diccionario, pero se reeamplaza. Lo estoy añadiendo de esta forma:

```
   for j in range(len(Repetidos)): 
         historias[m[j]]=Repetidos[j]
```

¿Está bien como lo hago? ya que al final me tira solo un elemento para cada clave del diccionario, la idea es que cada clave contenga varios elementos. O se debe hacer con "append"

Saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué elementos quieres agregar? ¿Qué claves quieres usar en el diccionario para acceder a dichos elementos?

Comment: Son puros números enteros. Por ejemplo las claves son: "1", "2", "3" y quiero añadir otros números a "1". Y obtener algo así: {1: [0, 3, 4], 2:[2,6].... de esa forma, se entiende? Lo que hace ahora es reemplazar y al final tira algo como {1: 0, 2: 2, 3: 11}

Comment: ¿Y qué números concretamente quieres agregar como una lista a cada entrada asociada a una clave del diccionario?  ¿m[i] donde i es la clave?

Comment: Tal y como lo tienes ahora, si tienes una lista `m` de números, estás guardando en el diccionario `historias` para cada clave, un único dato que es el valor igual a la clave. Si en lugar de asignar, haces `historias[m[j]].append(m[j])` (suponiendo que cada entrada de historias parte de una lista vacía), estás creando en cada entrada una lista de el mismo valor repetido tantas veces como aparezca en la lista `m`.

Comment: Jorge aunque te he respondido con la forma de solucionar el problema de que solo te guarda el último valor, lo que dice Carlos es totalmente cierto. Hay algo  extraño en la lógica de tu algoritmo.. Como dice Carlos con eso obtendras salidas del tipo `{1: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 2: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}`. Si sigues con problemas intenta explicar mejor que es lo que pretendes hacer y agregar más código. Saludos.

Comment: Ahhh si, lo que pasa es que puse m[j] a ambos lados, lo editaré. Gracias a ambos.

Comment: @FJSevilla Quizás lo que quiere es crear un diccionario donde las claves son los valores de la lista `m` y la entrada asociada a cada clave es una lista con los índices donde se encuentra ese valor en `m`. Si fuese así, en tu solución sólo tendrías que modificar el `for` final cambiando `m` por `Repetidos` y `append(m[j])` por `append(j)`.

Comment: La verdad m[j] es el nombre del repetido, el cual igual debo sumar en mi programa, por eso debo agregar la clave del diccionario como historia, además de las otras historias. Tanto las listas "m" como "repetidos" son sólo enteros que representan posiciones dentro de listas con muchos más datos.

Comment: Para tu modificación del código, la solución es la que te ha puesto @FJSevilla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al hacer eso estas reemplazando (reasignando) el valor de la clave en cada iteración, por lo que al final solo tendrás el último valor, el correspondiente a : `m[len(repetidos)-1]`.

Para agregar nuevos valores necesitarás usar una lista como valor y usar `append` como dices:

```
historias[m[j]].append(Repetidos[j])
```

Si haces esto debes definir una lista vacía previamente como valor a cada clave del diccionario. Esto debes hacerlo una sola vez y antes de agregar ningún valor a la lista:

```
historias[m[j]] = []
```

Una opción más cómoda es usar [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Cuando creas historias lo haces de esta forma:

```
from collections import defaultdict

historias = defaultdict(list)
```

Ahora cada vez que crees una nueva clave se crea una lista vacía como valor de forma automática. Por lo que no tienes que preocuparte de usar el método `append` sobre una lista que no existe.

```
for j in range(len(Repetidos)): 
     historias[m[j]].append(Repetidos[j])
```

Comment: Tengo este error lo conocen? "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'" @FJSevilla

Comment: se soluciona si hago lo siguiente "historias[str(m[mj[i]])].append(m[j])" pero me conviene que sea "int"

Comment: @JorgePonti eso es porque estas intentando usar `append` sobre un objeto `int` (entero). La diferencia entre `historias[str(m[mj[i]])]` y  `historias[m[mj[i]]]` solo afecta al tipo de la clave no al valor. Si tienes `historia[1] = 2`, no puedes usar `append` porque el valor es un entero. Necesitas que sea `historia[1]=[2]`. Por eso te decia antes lo de `defaultdict` o lo de inicializar cada pareja clave valor con `historia[clave] = []` antes de usar `append`.